# lua script not able to consume env variables in a docker container

Tags: docker, lua, environment-variables

Having the following Dockerfile

```
FROM openresty/openresty:alpine

RUN apk update && apk add bash \
       && apk add gettext envsubst


ENV REDIS_HOST \
    REDIS_PORT \
    REDIS_FULL_KEY_PREFIX \
    HTTP_PROTOCOL \
    WEB_HOST \
    UPSTREAM_HOST \
    PROXYPASS_NAME

RUN echo "env REDIS_HOST; env REDIS_PORT; env REDIS_FULL_KEY_PREFIX; env HTTP_PROTOCOL; env WEB_HOST; env UPSTREAM_HOST; env PROXYPASS_NAME;" > /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/lua-config.lua


COPY nginx.conf.template /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf.template
COPY test.lua /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf


ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "envsubst '${REDIS_HOST} ${REDIS_PORT} ${REDIS_FULL_KEY_PREFIX} ${HTTP_PROTOCOL} ${WEB_HOST} ${UPSTREAM_HOST} ${PROXYPASS_NAME}' < /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf.template > /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf && /usr/local/openresty/bin/openresty -g 'daemon off;error_log /dev/stdout debug;'"]
```

my nginx.conf where I call the lua script than it looks as it follows:

```
location ^~ /pages {
    rewrite_by_lua_file conf/test.lua;
    # more code 
   
}
```

I'm using docker compose to bring up the container

```
openresty:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
        REDIS_HOST: redis
        REDIS_FULL_KEY_PREFIX: "blah_blah"
        HTTP_PROTOCOL: "http://"
        WEB_HOST: localhost
        PROXYPASS_NAME: nginx
        UPSTREAM_HOST: localhost
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    networks:
      - proxynet
      - redis
```

I'm not able to consume in lua the ENV variables. For example when I try to get for example the `REDIS_HOST` env in my `test.lua` I get script nil

```
local cueRedisFqhn = os.getenv("REDIS_HOST")
local redisPort = os.getenv("REDIS_PORT") or "6379"
ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE, cueRedisFqhn)
```

How can adjust the dockerfile to make it available?

Comment: Is this the real dockerfile? How do you set env variables? Because according to the docs, the syntax is `ENV <key>=<value> ...`

Comment: How are you running your lua script, and what env variables are defined in that environment? See [mcve] for details about providing a complete and reproducible example that we can try to replicate your issue.

Comment: I use docker compose to init the env variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure environment variables are available in your Lua script within the Docker container, you need to pass them to the Nginx worker processes.
You can do so by modifying the `nginx.conf` configuration: use the [`env` directive in the `nginx.conf`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env) file to specify which environment variables should be passed to the Nginx worker processes.

First, add a step in the Dockerfile to append `env` directives to the `nginx.conf` file. Then, make sure your `nginx.conf` template has a placeholder where these directives can be inserted.

For example, your Dockerfile would be:

```
FROM openresty/openresty:alpine

RUN apk update && apk add bash \
       && apk add gettext envsubst

ENV REDIS_HOST \
    REDIS_PORT \
    REDIS_FULL_KEY_PREFIX \
    HTTP_PROTOCOL \
    WEB_HOST \
    UPSTREAM_HOST \
    PROXYPASS_NAME

# Generate the lua-config.lua file
RUN echo "env REDIS_HOST; env REDIS_PORT; env REDIS_FULL_KEY_PREFIX; env HTTP_PROTOCOL; env WEB_HOST; env UPSTREAM_HOST; env PROXYPASS_NAME;" > /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/lua-config.lua

COPY nginx.conf.template /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf.template
COPY test.lua /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf

# Add env directives to nginx.conf.template
RUN echo "env REDIS_HOST;\nenv REDIS_PORT;\nenv REDIS_FULL_KEY_PREFIX;\nenv HTTP_PROTOCOL;\nenv WEB_HOST;\nenv UPSTREAM_HOST;\nenv PROXYPASS_NAME;\n$(cat /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf.template)" > /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf.template

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "envsubst '${REDIS_HOST} ${REDIS_PORT} ${REDIS_FULL_KEY_PREFIX} ${HTTP_PROTOCOL} ${WEB_HOST} ${UPSTREAM_HOST} ${PROXYPASS_NAME}' < /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf.template > /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf && /usr/local/openresty/bin/openresty -g 'daemon off;error_log /dev/stdout debug;'"]
```

That Dockerfile now includes the `env` directives to pass the environment variables to Nginx.
In your Dockerfile, you are declaring the environment variables without assigning values to them. That approach is fine as long as you are providing the values through Docker Compose, as you mentioned in your reply/comment.

To integrate environment variables into your Nginx configuration, you will want to modify your `nginx.conf.template` to include placeholders for the `env` directives. These directives tell Nginx to pass the specified environment variables to its worker processes, making them accessible in your Lua script.

`nginx.conf.template`:

```
# Placeholder for env directives
env REDIS_HOST;
env REDIS_PORT;
env REDIS_FULL_KEY_PREFIX;
env HTTP_PROTOCOL;
env WEB_HOST;
env UPSTREAM_HOST;
env PROXYPASS_NAME;

# Rest of the nginx configuration
http {
    server {
        # Your server configuration

        location ^~ /pages {
            rewrite_by_lua_file conf/test.lua;
            # more code
        }

        # Other locations and directives
    }
}
```

When Nginx starts, it will process this template, and the environment variables you set in your Docker Compose file will be accessible in your Lua script using `os.getenv("VAR_NAME")`.